# Why is Snakemake not seeing symbol link files?

Tags: symlink, snakemake

I have a rule whose output files are symbolic link files.  Even though the link files are being made, Snakemake exits with a MissingOutputException and lists the output files as being missing.  If instead of making a symlink with "ln -s" I copy the files with "cp -p" it works.  I tried increasing the --latency-wait but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using relative path for source file when symlinking. Use absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Snakemake sees broken symlinks as missing output.